# Is it possible to define a global (header + footer) wrapper on react-native using react-navigation and nativebase

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, native-base

I am very new to React-Native, React navigation and nativebase. Roughly, I am trying to find a way to set the same header and footer on each screen of my application. The header contains the title + a login icon. The footer contains the navigation. What is the proper way to have a global header and a global footer to the application ?

I have tried defining a wrapper component (MainStructure) and add {this.props.children} in the content  but I get an error on this.props.navigation whenever I click the footer. For this error, I have tried adding navigation props manually to MainStructure it did not work. I have tried adding HOC withNavigation, no result neither.

I have tried defining a header component and a footer component and adding them everywhere in the component, but that's ugly + it does not work for some reason I don't get.

Finally, I have tried defining header in navigationOptions and defaultNavigationOptions it did not work neither.

this is the App code

```
const AppNavigator=createSwitchNavigator(
    {
        Home:Home,
        Search: Search,
        Account:Account,
        Login:Login
    },
    {
        initialRouteName:"Home",
    }
);
const AppContainer= createAppContainer(AppNavigator);

class App extends Component{


  render() {
    return (
        <MainStructure>
            <AppContainer/>
        </MainStructure>
    );
  }
}

export default App;

AppRegistry.registerComponent('Kioozi', ()=> App);
```

Here is the MainStructure code

```
class MainStructure extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        Text.defaultProps.uppercase=false
    }
    render() {

        return (
            <StyleProvider style={getTheme(variables)}>
                <Container>
                    <Header>
                        <Left/>
                        <Body>
                            <Title>{I18n.t('homepage.title')}</Title>
                        </Body>
                        <Right>
                            <Button transparent onPress={()=> this.props.navigation.navigate('Login')}>
                                <Icon name={'login'} type={"Entypo"}/>
                            </Button>
                        </Right>
                    </Header>
                    <Content padder>
                        {this.props.children}
                    </Content>
                    <Footer>
                        <FooterTab>
                            <Button badge vertical onPress={()=> this.props.navigation.navigate('Home')}>
                                <Badge><Text>2</Text></Badge>
                                <Icon name={"home"} type={"Entypo"}/>
                                <Text>{I18n.t('footer.home')}</Text>
                            </Button>
                            <Button badge vertical onPress={()=> this.props.navigation.navigate('Search')}>
                                <Badge><Text>2</Text></Badge>
                                <Icon name={"magnify"} type={"MaterialCommunityIcons"}/>
                                <Text>{I18n.t('footer.search')}</Text>
                            </Button>
                            <Button badge vertical onPress={()=> this.props.navigation.navigate('Account')}>
                                <Badge><Text>2</Text></Badge>
                                <Icon name={"account-outline"} type={"MaterialCommunityIcons"}/>
                                <Text>{I18n.t('footer.myAccount')}</Text>
                            </Button>
                        </FooterTab>
                    </Footer>
                </Container>
            </StyleProvider>
        );
    }
}

export default MainStructure;
```

I used createSwitchNavigator as I want to use the bottomTab from nativebase and not from react-navigation.
Expected Result : whenever I press a tab, I get the related screen with the header and footer.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the `<AppContainer />` like below with importing `Header` and `Footer` from nativebase

```
<MainStructure>
  <View style={{flex:1}}>
    <Header>.....</Header>
    <AppContainer />

  <Footer>.....</Footer>
 </View>
</MainStructure>;
```